# Coldbox Module Routes

Tags: routes, coldfusion, coldbox

Is there a way, to have multiple routes go through to the same module ?
I have tried adding the

```
addModuleRoutes(pattern="/blog", module="test");
```

to the config/Router.cfc
But I just always get the error

```
Error loading module routes as the module requested 'test' is not loaded.
```

Does anyone know why the module is not being loaded ?

Comment: Hard to tell from this snippet, but if you remove the route, reinit the app and then try to hit that module, with index.cfm?event=test:handler.action does the module work? I wonder if the folder name doesn't match "test" - common issue